# How to close all active applications from my Android app?

Tags: android

I have a my Android app, and I would like to close all other active applications from my app.
Is there a way to do it in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this,but it is not recommended:

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

Comment: How to kill foreground apps if we are running this from a background service?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
int p = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(p);
```

Comment: ,I am working on the same and If You have working code then share..Because whatever you are saying is not working.

Comment: @user2204790 See above answer is Updated

Comment: The app is closed by not removed from overview button recents screen.
Also, will this work for other apps?

Answer (score 0):

To ***avoid to killing system apps*** you can do this,i include code for particlur brand like Huawei  have own apps (which often contain **Huawei**) and samsung have own so this code avoid to kill system apps and will close all other apps.System apps often contain **android** and **adil** is my package which i dont wanna kill

```
    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
        getApplicationContext().getSystemService( getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(int pnum = 0; pnum < procInfos.size(); pnum++)
{
     if((procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("android")||(procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("system")||(procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("huawei")||(procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("adil")) 
     {
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "system apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    else
    {
        actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(procInfos.get(pnum).processName);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "killed "+procInfos.get(pnum).processName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```