# How to kill all running applications in android?

Tags: android

I want to kill all running applications in android. so for this task, I've implemented the following code. But it is not working. The app still remains running.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo service : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
    Log.i("process name " , service.processName);
    
    android.os.Process.killProcess(service.pid);
    }
```

So where did I make a mistake in the code?

Comment: Let me tell you i have tested it in AVD not in device .So is there any way it only runs in real device ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- You can use `Process.killProcess(int pid)` to kill processes that have the same `UID` with your App.
- You can use `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName)`,with `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission in your manifest(for API >= 8) or `ActivityManager.restartPackage (String packageName)`(for API < 8) to kill specified process,except of forground process.

So if you would to kill all other processes when your program is foreground process,you would to use `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses` or `ActivityManager.restartPackage`:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

   ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   String myPackage = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(myPackage)) continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

In above snippet code,each process will be killed unless it be process of your App or system process.
References:
[How to close all active applications from my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996536/how-to-close-all-active-applications-from-my-android-app/6996635#6996635)
[How do task killers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502340/how-do-task-killers-work)

Comment: I dont understand what the line --------         if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue; does..!! could you please explain

Comment: @lalith If ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1) be true,it means that this App is a system App (and we have not stop a system App),so we continue.

Comment: will it remove apps from recent apps list (displayed by long pressing the home button)?

Comment: @UmerFarooq I mentioned it before in the answer: `In above snippet code,each process will be killed unless it be process of your App or system process.`

Comment: recent apps are not being removed

Comment: How to kill foreground apps if we are running this from a background service?

Answer (score 5):

You have another possibility if the device is rooted (has superuser rights).

You can invoke an external process that would use the su rights. But note that it's probably a bad design as Android OS should be the only one to kill processes.

```
try {
   Process rootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su" });

   String command = "kill - 9 <pid>";

   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(rootProcess.getOutputStream()), 2048);
   try {
      bw.write(command);
      bw.newLine();
      bw.flush();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle error
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   // Device not rooted!            
}
```

Comment: I tested it and still app running but killed

Comment: Your phone has to be rooted

Answer (score 2):

According to doc [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)

> Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process
>   based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions
>   on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only
>   the process running the caller's packages/application and any
>   additional processes created by that app

I test it, and it only kill process hosted my App.

Comment: Then is it impossible to kill others running applications ?

Comment: I do little search about killing external app. But, nothing usefull find. In the other hand, we have many Task Managers app who can kill any external process. So, this is possible - but unfortunatelly i don't know how yet.

Answer (score 1):

Reflect to force stop

`ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
Method method = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager").getMethod("forceStopPackage", String.class);
method.invoke(am, pkgName);`

You should add this system permission:

> android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES

Comment: android studio warning that it will only be granted to system apps.