# Kill all recent applications in android

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher, android-applicationinfo

When i press home key for long time in my android device.I get list of all recent applications. Now i want to kill all my recent applications pro grammatically from within my application.
I am able to get list of all recent applications but not able to kill all apps.

I want to achieve it with android version 4.x

Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get a list of `RunningTaskInfo` records using the following:

```
 [public List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> getRunningTasks (int maxNum)][1]
```

[**Reference**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)

After that, you can use the process-ids in that list to terminate the relevant processes
using either

```
activityManager.killBackgroundProcess(pid);
                    or
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

depending upon whether you can kill that process. Way to kill these is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560009/759019).

Comment: I tried as you guided me but still all recent apps exists.Can you please guide me more how to achieve it ?

Comment: See [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7560009/759019) for guidance on killing the processes, which you do not have direct privileges to kill

Comment: So what you are saying is that you need to have a rooted phone and the killing app to have escalated privileges for this to work.

Comment: No. No. If you read through that answer, you will see `The second API works by telling the built in ActivityManager that you want to kill processes associated with a specific Package. ` because `killProcess()` can only kill processes that belong to that user. Each application runs as a different user in the Dalvik VM. Hence, the work-around with the `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission. [**(Reference)**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I tried by ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName) but it is not working and process remains running.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Process.killProcess()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29). But it wont allways work:

> Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows
>   us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will
>   still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able
>   to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's
>   packages/application and any additional processes created by that app;
>   packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's
>   processes.