# How to exit selected running applications using process id

Tags: android

I am using this code to stop the selected running applications in android phone:

```
Button view = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View view){

String appname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("appname");
String pname=appname.split("\n")[3];
int id=Integer.parseInt(pname);
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
```

The Id is correct but this code is not working... any help??
Is there any other code to kill processes by using their id??

Comment: the problem is in line  android.os.Process.killProcess(id); i need aternate for this...

Comment: Try to put finish after killProcess

Comment: You get a crash? Or just close without kill?

Comment: close without kill....

Comment: i have pakage name, app name,id plz tell me any method using any of theses to stop seleted

Comment: myPid() kills the currently running application...not seleted one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you check the [Android API for Kill Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29) it says the following:

> Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app; packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's processes.

This means you're not able to kill other apps except the ones your app package is in.

This answer explains why it is so and how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560009/1306012

Comment: you mean i cant stop other apps using my app?

Comment: No, as a third party developer you do not get to **act maliciously** towards other developers apps, regardless if they may be annoy-ware which "deserves it".

Answer (score 1):

You need the package name of the app you want to kill (for example com.facebook.katana) and then call

```
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
//for example: kill the facebook app
//ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.facebook.katana);
```

However, you need the permission `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` defined in your manifest.

Comment: Sure you can. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES

Comment: killBackground process does not kill the mainActivity of the apps...it only exits some background processes..i tried this its not exiting the application..for example i open adobe reader...then without closing it start the app which stops the existing running processes...i select adobe and stop it using "killbackground processes" and check again...but still adobe reader is not closed..actually i want to stop it..

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> services = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
String service1name = service[1].processName;
```

you can get all running process's package names, check which one you want to kill, choose that

```
process get process id by service.pid.
```

and call

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(service.pid);
```

Comment: I think he need to kill others process not his process.

Comment: i dont want to stop this running app butt the app which is seleted by using this app ...any other app

Comment: i used toast to check whether i am getting id correctly or not... id is correct... but this kill process method  doesnt kill the app selected

Comment: what is service in service.pid??/