# kill an app running in the background in android

Tags: android, kill-process

I am using `android.os.Process.killProcess(myProcessPID)` function to kill some running app, but this doesn't work...

What is the proper/other way to kill an app? Just like a task manager?

(My app has a superior permissions)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I kill processes in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847502/how-can-i-kill-processes-in-android)

Comment: please, post the Exception you're getting.

Comment: There's no exception - it's just doesn't work.