# How can I close running background apps except mine?

Tags: android, sdk

When the user clicks on the "Close running Apps" Button then every application which is running in the background needs to be closed except my current application.
How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: You should not be killing your's or any other apps. Android handles the closing of apps itself not the developer and it is bad practice to kill an app.

Comment: Don't do this. Firstly Android does it better, secondly do you really want every other app developers app being killed by yours, do you think your users would want this. What's your app? I want to know so I can be sure to never, ever install it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill all running applications in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397668/how-to-kill-all-running-applications-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at:
[How to kill all running applications in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397668/how-to-kill-all-running-applications-in-android)
I think the answer there would really help you

Comment: link is good one. Proper explanation is present there.

Comment: Sorry ignore what I posted, didn't realise it was a Stack Overflow link. My bad! Have a +1 :)

Comment: @UserQuestion 
IN the Code of hasanghaforian it says:
`(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`
What is `context` because there is no `context`defined?

Comment: @user3812130 I would advise you to take a look on googles documentation of context, and you could have a look at this post for more information and usage of it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android