# How to kill all active processes from Android phone with code in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cache-control

**Hi**

How to kill all active processes from Android phone with code in my app?
I read couple of articles like [How to kill all running applications in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397668/how-to-kill-all-running-applications-in-android) and tried this code:

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> packages;

    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    Log.d("Packages" , String.valueOf(packages));

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);

        Log.d("Cleaned" , String.valueOf(packageInfo.packageName));

    }
```

Logcat does show me all the active processes, but no of them have closed/nothing happens.

**Yes,** I do have included this in my Manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

I there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am searching for the same.