# Call an implecit intent for perticular time interval

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I want to start another application from my application with the help of an implicit intent and want the second activity to get stoped after a perticular interval of time.

For eg:
To open chrome i could do it like

```
 String url = "http://www.example.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    try {
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Chrome is probably not installed
        // Try with the default browser
        i.setPackage(null);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

But i want chrome to automatically get closed after 1 minute. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: YOu add a Handler, TimerTask, Runnable, any form of thread and add either a time interval, postDelayed, sleep to add the delay

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can kill an application; First you have to find running application via `ActivityManager` like this answer:

[How to find the currently running applications programatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android)

Then you can kill it like implied here:

[How to kill all running applications in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397668/how-to-kill-all-running-applications-in-android)

Though me and Google don't really recommend this ><